# Quality loss after combining two images with PIL and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm using PIL and numpy to combine two images while one is a .jpg and the other image is represented by a numpy array, which defines a mask that I want to put on top of the original image (basically just a matrix with one and zero entries and the same size as the .jpg). PIL’s composite function works just fine for that but for some reason, after saving the composite image, the file size shrinks to approximately 1/3 of the original image size. Can someone explain this behavior to me?

Here's a code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageColor

rgb = ImageColor.getrgb('black')

# Read image and write into numpy array
image = Image.open('test_image.jpg')
(im_width, im_height) = image.size

# Create empty mask
mask = np.zeros((im_width, im_height))

# Composite image and mask
solid_color = np.expand_dims(np.ones_like(mask), axis=2) * 
  np.reshape(list(rgb), [1, 1, 3])
pil_solid_color = 
  Image.fromarray(np.uint8(solid_color)).convert('RGBA')
pil_mask = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(255.*mask)).convert('L')

image = Image.composite(pil_solid_color, image, pil_mask)

# save image
image.save('test_image_with_mask.jpg')
```

Code was inspired by tnesorflow's object detection api. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jpg is lossy. Jpg has parameters. You do not set any.

Comment: yeah I already figured out that i can set a quality value in image.save(..., quality = 95), but I have no clue how to perfectly keep the original quality. A quality value of 100 almost doubles the file size. Basically I just want to black out some parts of the original image, which are defined in the mask array. Any suggestions how to do this efficiently?

Comment: No. Impossible. Only a very very limited [subset](http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/) of things can be done in jpeg without decode-reencode and therefore losing quality or efficiency. Either store as jpg and live with the loss or store lossless and live with increase of size. That's why image-pipelines usually work with lossless formats as long as possible.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, a lot of things are much clearer now!